# PureScript "inner" quantified type

Tags: purescript

I assume I got the terminology in the tile wrong - let me know what I should have used instead for the below.

In [PureScript by Example, section 8.17 Mutable State](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-mutable-state), there's a discussion of the type of `runST`:

```
runST :: forall a eff. (forall h. Eff (st :: ST h | eff) a) -> Eff eff a
```

> > The thing to notice here is that the region type h is quantified inside the parentheses on the left of the function arrow. That means that whatever action we pass to runST has to work with any region h whatsoever.

I understand the end goal, but can someone clarify this statement from the perspective of types and how this gets restricted as per above?

If possible, can the difference be shown on simpler types, e.g. what is the difference between:

```
f1 :: forall i o. Array i -> Array o
f2 :: forall o. (forall i. Array i) -> Array o
```

I think a short example would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What values inhabit the type `Array a`?

Well, if you know what `a` is, or something about `a`, then you might be able to give concrete examples. If `a` is known to be `Int`, then `[1, 2, 3]` is a fine answer. If `a` has a `Monoid` instance then `[mempty]` works. However, if you don't know anything about `a` then the only answer you can confidently give is `[]`.

What values inhabit the type `forall a. Array a`?

Any value inhabiting that type has to inhabit `Array a` for any choice of `a`. Since we don't know anything about `a`, the answer is "only `[]`" again. So the `forall` constrains us to only a single possible implementation of a type in this case.

Now `forall a. Array a` is a type like any other, so it can appear as the argument type of a function. As a caller of such a function, you only have one possible value that you can provide. As the *implementor* of that function, you can choose to use the argument with *any* type `a` (since it must work with whatever type you choose).

The same is true for `runST`. The implementor of `runST` can choose to call your action with any `h` it pleases, so it (conceptually) generates a new memory region for you to work with. As the caller, you have to work with whatever memory region you are given, without knowing anything about it. This means that you can only use the actions provided (`newSTRef`, `writeSTRef`, etc.) abstractly, and any references you create cannot leave the scope of the `runST` block (the type variable `h` doesn't exist outside that scope, after all), which allows `runST` to return a pure result safely.

So, `forall` is a useful tool for restricting the values that can be provided as function arguments.